# Converting xcode objective c themes and template to mono/xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, themes, xamarin

I have bought some templates from App Design Vault and they are in XCode/Objective C. I would like to use them in Xamarin Studio/MonoTouch projects, how do I convert them so that they can be used similar to how some themes has been converted in [Xamarin's Components Store](http://components.xamarin.com/view/black-leather-theme/)?

Example of how the App Design Vault template is structured/layout can be downloaded from their website, they have a free template called Ocean: http://emitymeapps.us1.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=088ecce4e59f7a30e9aa859af&id=e59abf1e54

Thanks.

Comment: Can you somehow post how these themes are setup? If it is mainly image files, those should be easy to use in MonoTouch.

Comment: @jonathanpeppersless - I can't post the template that I've bought, but they have a free template called Ocean that is layout/structure exactly the same to the one that I've bought. You can get download the template from here http://emitymeapps.us1.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=088ecce4e59f7a30e9aa859af&id=e59abf1e54

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if you look in the AppDelegate.m file of their sample project, there are functions like this:

```
-(void)customizeiPhoneTheme
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
     setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated:NO];

    UIImage *navBarImage = [[UIImage tallImageNamed:@"menubar.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 15, 5, 15)];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBarImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


    UIImage *barButton = [[UIImage tallImageNamed:@"menubar-button.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 4, 0, 4)];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:barButton forState:UIControlStateNormal 
                                          barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    UIImage *backButton = [[UIImage tallImageNamed:@"back.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 14, 0, 4)];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButton forState:UIControlStateNormal 
                                                    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


    UIImage *minImage = [UIImage tallImageNamed:@"ipad-slider-fill"];
    UIImage *maxImage = [UIImage tallImageNamed:@"ipad-slider-track.png"];
    UIImage *thumbImage = [UIImage tallImageNamed:@"ipad-slider-handle.png"];

    [[UISlider appearance] setMaximumTrackImage:maxImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[UISlider appearance] setMinimumTrackImage:minImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:thumbImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:thumbImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage tallImageNamed:@"tabbar.png"];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];


    [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage tallImageNamed:@"tabbar-active.png"]];

}
```

You are basically going to have to port this code to MonoTouch and add their images to your project. But it should be pretty easy, here is a couple lines of code translated to C#:

```
 UIImage navBarImage = UIImage.FromFile("menubar.png").CreateResiableImage(new UIEdgeInsets(5, 15, 5, 15));

 UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage(navBarImage, UIBarMetrics.Default);
```

Check for mistakes, I did that off the top of my head. I'm also not sure what `[UIImage tallImageNamed]` is, it must be their own extension. I think you should just use `UIImage.FromFile`.

Comment: thanks for the instruction, I'll take a look and see if I can convert them to C#!

Comment: Did you managed to convert it? I'm struggling with lots of code in the /library and /theme folder... Some of them dont have the same methods/classes in Xamarin.iOS... I bought a theme too but stuck with it...

Comment: Did you post a question on your problem? Give some details in a new question. I convert Obj-C samples to C# all the time, usually only obscure or new APIs are missing.